# Transform too dense data

Tags: d3.js, plotly

Trying to display line chart using plotly.js, my data are collected per second. I fed my graph but the result looks strange even if I zoom in, to very low detail where it should be displayed per seconds.

Are there any methods I could use to preprocess the data so it would display well in different scales (as I zoom in and out)?

```js
var gd = document.getElementById('tester');

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    showgrid: true,
    tickformat: "%H:%M:%S",
  },
  margin: {
    l: 40,
    b: 40,
    r: 30,
    t: 20
  },
  hovermode: 'x',
};

var draw = function(data, layout) {
  Plotly.newPlot(gd, data, layout, {
    showLink: false,
    displaylogo: false
  });
};


var dataurl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fhurta/6c53839fbc91a363d62966a972a5e4a2/raw/2cd735f0b024e496164dacec92fa4a7abcd5da2e/series.csv';

Plotly.d3.csv(dataurl, function(rows) {
  var data = [{
    type: 'scatter',
    x: rows.map(function(row) {
      return new Date(row['Time']);
    }),
    y: rows.map(function(row) {
      return row['Value1'];
    }),
    line: {
      width: 1
    }
  }];

  draw(data, layout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: You can do data-binning to display data at different scales. But I bet there are libraries that bin data automatically based on given window and zoom level.